# How to select a locator by an attribute?

Tags: javascript, attributes, playwright

When a product has no stock, I have the attributes:

```html
<div class="sizeButton__container js-quickAddToCartSize -default-classic js-outOfStockSize -outOfStock " title="" data-productid="654354128" data-variantid="654354128002" data-available="null" data-allocation="0" >
</div>
```

When my product has stock, I have the attributes

```html
<div class="sizeButton__container js-quickAddToCartSize -default-classic  " title="" data-productid="654354128" data-variantid="654354128003" data-available="true" data-allocation="91">
```

I searched but I don't find how to click on the locator with the attribute `data-available = true` or `data-allocation != 0`.

I tried

```js
import { defineConfig } from '@playwright/test';

export default defineConfig({
  use: {
    testIdAttribute: 'data-available'
  }
});
```

And to call the locator with `data-available('true')` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using `getByTestId` in your locator? Please show the actual locator, and preferably a runnable, complete test script.

Answer (score 1):

For this, you should use the `or()` method. This creates the locator based on one or the other. Heres some reading on it: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-or

In your case, your locator could be something like:

```
const product = this.page
  .locator("[data-available='null']")
  .or(this.page.locator("[data-available='true']"));
```

Then, to use one of the above, you can wait for it. Something to the effect of:

```
await expect(product.first()).toBeVisible();
```

Or click it:

```
await product.first().click();
```

Note the use of the `first()` method, which can be replaced with `nth(0)` if you wish, though Id recommend using `first()`.